# Improving MATLAB code speed

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, execution-time

Would be grateful for some pointers. I am reading about 1M rows of data and it is taking almost 24 hours with the following code. How can I improve the execution time?

The array `Day` contains the value of the n<sup>th</sup> day from the start and there are more then one record for a particular day. The program checks if a particular id (stored in `unique_id`) is repeated within 180 days.

```
%// calculating the number of repeats within 180 days
fid2 = 'data_050913/Unique_id_repeat_count1.xlsx';
fid1 = 'data_050913/data_050913_2000.csv';

fid_data = fopen(fid1);
data     = fgetl(fid_data); %// the first line, title line
ep       = 0; %// position point number

while 1
    data = fgetl(fid_data);
    if(length(data)<10)
      break;
    end
    ep = ep+1;
    id = find(data == ',');
    unique_id(ep) = str2num(data(1:id(1)-1)); 
    day(ep) = str2num(data(id(8)+1:id(9)-1)); 
end

repeat = zeros(ep,1);

tic
i = 1; 
count = 0;
while i <= ep
    j = i+1;
    while ( (j<=ep) && (day(j)<= day(i)+179) )
        if unique_id(i) == unique_id(j)
           count = 1;
           break;
        end
        j = j+1;
    end

    repeat(i,1) = count;

    count = 0;
    i = i+1;
end
toc

i = 1;
k = 1;
while i<=ep
    count = repeat(i,1);
    j=i;
    while (day(j) == day(i))
        count = repeat(j,1)+count;
        j = j+1;
        if j > ep
            break;
        end
    end

    day_final(k,1)= day(i);
    repeat_final(k,1) = count;

    k = k+1;
    i = j;
end

xlswrite(fid2,day_final,'Repeat_Count','A2');
xlswrite(fid2,repeat_final,'Repeat_Count','B2');
```

Thanks

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: couple of seconds...your point?

Comment: Just for clarification: *which part* of your code eats so much time? If it's the first loop, look at @Dr.ABT's answer and/or read about `textscan`, `importdata`, `textread`, etc. Have you used the profiler?

Comment: Can you run it on a smaller file (maybe 10000 lines) and profile it to see where is the bottleneck?

Comment: For some reason if I remove the break; the code runs faster...can it be true?

Comment: Is the number of unique values in `unique_id` much less than 1 million (few thousand at most)? In that case you may want to loop over that instead of over the 1 million rows.

Comment: Reading files with `fgetl` can be slow. Try the faster [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) (don't worry, it can handle 1M rows!). Also, try vectorizing your loops. If you elaborate more on what your program does (perhaps provide a short example and the desired output), it'll be easier to help you with that.

Comment: About the *break* - yes it can be because it inhibits vectorization (not the matlab one - but the one from the compiler - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28parallel_computing%29 )

Comment: The point of `sort` would be to estimate the lower limit of the complexity: by sorting all the id's one can more easily find duplicates -- OTOH, there's already a built-in function `unique()` in matlab. Also one can utilize unique(days), to locate all the unique days in the first list; then iterate that and use `unique(unique_id(days >= dayX .* days <= (dayX + 179)))`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below runs about 200x faster than your original code and gives the same result.

Of course, the speed-up is dependant on the distribution of the input data and my assumptions may be incorrect (I have 1000 unique IDs and on average 19 records per day).

I've also written some code to generate data similar to what I believe your input data is.

```
% Generate Input data 
ep = 100000;

isRepeatedDay = rand(1,ep) < 0.95;
day = cumsum(~isRepeatedDay);
unique_ids = 1:1000;
unique_id_indices = round(rand(ep,1)*length(unique_ids));
unique_id_indices(unique_id_indices < 1) = 1;
unique_id_indices(unique_id_indices > length(unique_id_indices) ) = length(unique_id_indices);

unique_id = unique_ids(unique_id_indices);

%Process the input data to find repeats
tic
repeat = zeros(ep,1);
[unique_values,~,indices] = unique(unique_id);
for uv_index = 1:length(unique_values)
    uv = unique_values(uv_index);
    uv_indices = find(indices == uv_index);
    for i=1:length(uv_indices)-1
        daysDifference = day(uv_indices(i+1)) - day(uv_indices(i));
        if daysDifference <= 179
            repeat(uv_indices(i),1) = 1;
        end
    end
end
toc
```

Answer (score 3):

if not already doing this, ensure you allocate all memory up-front where possible. I've seen Matlab scripts go from 24-hours to 8 minutes by doing this.

Use the [`zeros`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html) function to preallocate memory for all growing arrays (`day`, `unique_id`, `repeat`, `day_final` and `repeat_final`).

```
x = zeros(1000); %// Creates a 1000 element array of all zeros
```

Comment: My Matlab is a little rusty. What about unique_id, day_final, repeat_final, day?

Comment: Sorry, I missed those. Nevertheless, your answer is a good point, but is probably not the whole story. Growing arrays in loops got a lot better in R2011a, so 1) it depends on the OP's MATLAB version, and 2) we don't know which parts of the code eat so much time.

Comment: The time is from the tic to toc..rest of the code does not take too much time

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way I would do it if `unique_id` can have many different values (and maybe even if it doesn't).

The operation takes under 5 seconds on my system:

```
x = round(rand(1000000,1)*10);
result = zeros(size(x));
windowsize = 180;
for t = 1:(numel(x)-windowsize)
    result(t) = sum(x(t+1:t+windowsize)==x(t));
end
```

I think this is what you need, make sure to check whether you want to look 'forward' or 'backward'.

Answer (score 1):

- You can check which line needs most time with MATLAB's [profiler](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/profile.html).
- One thing you should know: MATLAB ist fast with vectors and matrices but it's usually very slow in loops. You should always try to work with the whole vector (or matrice) if possible. There are various ways to do this.
- One way is logical indexing. I think this should work for a part of your Problem. At

first I will show you a little example how logical indexing works:

```
vector=[0 4 5 2 4]

logicalIndex=(vector==4) %the type of logicalIndex is bool!

excerpOfVector=vector(logicalIndex) %some other ways to use logial Indexing 
excerpOfVectorSecondVariation=zeros(1,length(vector)) 
excerpOfVectorSecondVariation(logicalIndex)=vector(logicalIndex)
vector(vector < 5) = 11;            %implicit use of logical indexing
```

- You should change your messy while loops into for loops! ;-)

Comment: I think you've missed the requirement that the number of elements to scan is set by the day number recorded in the matching day vector.  You need to scan across 180 days not 180 elements.